# Where clause in Spark with between for element in array of struct?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, where-clause

I have this two case class :

```
case class Doc(posts: Seq[Post], test: String)
case class Post(postId: Int, createdTime: Long)
```

I create a sample df :

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
Doc(Seq(
  Post(1, 1),
  Post(2, 3),
  Post(3, 8),
  Post(4, 15)
), null),
Doc(Seq(
  Post(5, 6),
  Post(6, 9),
  Post(7, 12),
  Post(8, 20)
), "hello") )).toDF()
```

So what i want is , return online Doc with posts where createTime is between x et y .
For example, for x = 2 et y = 9, i want this result with the same schema of the origin df :

```
+--------------+
|         posts|
+--------------+
|[[2,3], [3,8]]|
|[[5,6], [6,9]]|
+--------------+
```

So i tried lot of combination of where, but i doesn't work. 
I tried to use `map(_.filter(...))`, but the problem i don't want to do `toDF().as[Doc]`

Any help ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you add one of the things that you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

- By using UDF
- By using explode and collect
- By using databricks tools

**UDF**

UDF is the catch all way. You basically create a custom function to do the work. Unlike converting to dataset it will not construct the entire Doc class but instead would handle only the relevant data:

```
def f(posts: Seq[Row]): Seq[Post] = {
  posts.map(r => Post(r.getAs[Int](0), r.getAs[Long](1))).filter(p => p.createdTime > 3 && p.createdTime < 9))
}
val u = udf(f _)
val filtered = df.withColumn("posts", u($"posts"))
```

**Using explode and collect_list**

```
df.withColumn("posts", explode($"posts")).filter($"posts.createdTime" > 3 && $"posts.createdTime" < 9).groupBy("test").agg(collect_list("posts").as("posts"))
```

This is probably less efficient than the previous one but it is a one liner (and at one point or another in the future it might get optimized).

**Using databricks tools**

If you are working on databricks cloud you can use higher order functions.
see [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/24/working-with-nested-data-using-higher-order-functions-in-sql-on-databricks.html) for more information. Since this is not a general general spark option I will not go over it.
Hopefully, in the future they will integrate it into standard spark (I found [this jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19480) on the subject but it is not currently supported).